# Is weak self needed in NSKeyValueObservation observe() closure?

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing

I have:

```
private var statusLabel:   UILabel!
private var errorObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

self.errorObserver = self.viewModel.observe(\.errorString)
{ [weak self] (viewModel, change) in
    self?.statusLabel.text = viewModel.errorString
}
```

Is `[weak self]` needed here?

Comment: Without `[weak self]` you have a retain cycle. That may be acceptable or wanted (if you remove the observer explicitly eventually) or not.

Comment: @MartinR This new (Swift 4 / Xcode 9) KVO form no longer requires explicit removal of the observer in `deinit`. Doesn't that change things?

Comment: I don't think so (perhaps I am overlooking something!). You can easily check it by adding `deinit { print("deinit") }` to your observing class and see if that is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you do need the `[weak self]`. Not having to explicitly remove the observer in `deinit` is a nice convenience that makes sure the Observation Center does not send notifications to de-initialized observers, but does not absolve you from having to manage memory for the closure.

Apple's Official Documents (The Swift Programming Language 4.0.3) states:

> By default, a closure expression captures constants and variables from its surrounding scope with strong references to those values. You can use a capture list to explicitly control how values are captured in a closure.
>
> A capture list is written as a comma-separated list of expressions surrounded by square brackets, before the list of parameters. If you use a capture list, you must also use the in keyword, even if you omit the parameter names, parameter types, and return type.
>
> ....
>
> If the type of the expression’s value is a class, you can mark the expression in a capture list with weak or unowned to capture a weak or unowned reference to the expression’s value.

[Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.0.3).” iBooks.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11)

If you do not mark the expression `self` in a capture list, a strong reference cycle will be created. A strong reference cycle is created because classes are reference types, and closures are reference types. When the body of the closure refers to an instance of a class, a reference to the class instance is created by the closure. By default, this is a strong reference, unless you use a capture list to define a different type of reference. The official notes even [say](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11):

> Swift requires you to write `self.someProperty` or `self.someMethod()` (rather than just `someProperty` or `someMethod()`) whenever you refer to a member of `self` within a closure. This helps you remember that it’s possible to capture `self` by accident.

In your case, you are referencing a label inside the body of the closure. The fact that you need to write

```
self?.statusLabel.text = viewModel.errorString
```

instead of simply

```
.statusLabel.text = viewModel.errorString
```

is a hint to you to use `self` inside a capture list.